# Standalone application launcher similar to Linux Mint's

Tags: linux, launcher

I'm setting up an Archlinux box with a tiling windows manager (xmonad for the moment). However I'd like to mimic Windows/Linux Mint's keyboard shortcut:

- `<win>+<arrows>` for moving windows.
- `<win>` for start menu/application launcher.

I like mint's launcher, because I can press `<win>` and start typing to search for applications.

A feature it doesn't have is tab completion for files and directories, which I would really like.

There are many launchers, and they are all very configurable which I like, but it would be best if it had this features out of the box. Any recommendations?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried [Launchy](http://www.launchy.net/), [Synapse](https://launchpad.net/synapse-project), or [Gnome Do](http://do.cooperteam.net/)?

Comment: No, have you used them? Do you know if they will work with a tiling windows manager?